# Grape::Entity for Customize Response Explanation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I 'm working on Grape::Entity for customize Response
But when I see documentation on
[Grape::Entity](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-entity)

it says that with grap::entity we can decide on run time that which attributes to send & which not.
but I 'm not able to understand CODE even with given hints

```
expose :ip, if: { type: :full }
expose :ip, if: lambda { |instance, options| options[:type] == :full } # exposed if the function evaluates to true
expose :ip, if: :type # exposed if :type is available in the options hash
expose :ip, if: { type: :full } # exposed if options :type has a value of :full
expose :ip, unless: ... # the opposite of :if
expose :last_reply, using: API::Entities::Status do |status, options|
     status.replies.last
end

with_options(format_with: :iso_timestamp) do
    expose :created_at
    expose :updated_at
end

expose :digest do |status, options|
    Digest::MD5.hexdigest status.txt
end
```

I 'll really appreciate if someone explain it line by line

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll give it a try.

One thing you should know is that you can pass optional attributes to your Grape::Entity when you call it in your Grape endpoint:

```
present statuses, with: API::Entities::Status, type: :full
```

You can pass anything into the Entity object (e.g. `type`).

With these optional attributes you can work inside the entity.

- line 1: if `type` has the value `:full`, `:ip` is exposed
- line 2: same as line 1, but capsulated inside a lambda. You can access the `instance` and the `options` hash inside the block.
- line 3: if `type` is present in the entity, `:ip` is exposed
- line 4: identical to line 1
- line 5: as the comment says
- line 6-8: this is a nested Entity. `:using` declares which Entity class is used for this exposing. The block sets the instance that is passed to the Entity, in this case the last object of `status.replies`.
- line 10-13: You can format date or time objects with a `with_options` block. In this case, the `:iso_timestamp` formatter is used.
- line 15-17: This is another way of exposing. In this example you expose a digest of the `status.txt`.

I hope that this will help you somehow.